# Woocommerce cannot see products in wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with the `wp-admin` interface in woo-commerce. I have around 14k products and they show up when I browse the website as a user, but I cannot see or modify them in `wp-admin -> products`. It says 14k products found but nothing is showed.

I have disabled every plugin apart from Woo-commerce and I have selected the default theme and nothing changes. I have no idea what else to do... I have not overridden Woo-commerce pages or functions.

PS: I am using WordPress 4.1 and Woo-commerce 2.2.10

Comment: Is there any js confliction issue?

Comment: There is no custom code added, so I believe not. The Inspector from Firefox doesn't detect an error

Comment: Check your configuration using this link : http://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/

Comment: Thank you, but I followed everything step-by=step and nothing changes. Everything is as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem, I found the solution.
Because I have too many products, the page timeout was reached and it stopped loading, without saying so.

The solution is divided in two. First, you need to change the php.ini file and add the following line: `memory_limit = 4096M` for 4 GB. If you use Cpanel, you can do this directly from WHM interface.

The second step is adding this line to wp-config.php, before including wp-settings.php: `define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );`

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I'd suggest raising this as a bug with WooCommerce. You shouldn't be expected to let each script that runs on PHP to have 4GB available. Also, why make 4GB available when you're limiting it to 256MB anyway? I'd probably change the server value to 300MB.