# Cannot search products on wp-admin of woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Scenario: I have my searchbox on my front page of my website. On that searchbox, I can search the product by SKU and product name.

**Problem**: I can search a product on client's page/Front-end but **not on wp-admin** of the website.

I already tried this : [Woocommerce cannot see products in wp-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598605/woocommerce-cannot-see-products-in-wp-admin) , but still no result found.

Something strange!

Does anybody know?

Comment: can you please give more details? what happens when you try to search? it hangs? gives timeout? you get 0 results?

Comment: I was able to solve my problem and posted my answer below. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of those developers who may also encounter same problem, that's why I want to put it here for future reference.

I have been backtracking and searching answers on the internet but I found none. I tried to review my functions.php inside the theme and found this code below:

```
 function __search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query ) { 
   global $wpdb;
   $entry = isset($_GET['s']) ? $_GET['s'] : '';     
   if(  $entry ){
      $search =  "MY SQL QUERY HERE....."; 
    }        
   return $search;
 }
 add_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2 );
```

The above code was inserted inside the functions.php in order to overwrite the query.

`posts_search` filter, overrrides the product search on my back-end of search though my query was mistaken that's why the problem exists.

**I just removed the code and everything works fine.**